# How to remove the Cognito Forms Branding

Tags: cognito-forms

I have been using Cognito Forms for a while now, but when I try to create a new form I am now seeing "powered by cognito forms" at the bottom of my new form.

Is it possible to remove this?

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you had not noticed this before?
Or it could be that you had one of the paid plans which has by now expired.

As per the site [Pricing](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing) page, the only plan where the company's brand appears is the "*Individual*" (free) plan.
Please look for the "*REMOVABLE COGNITO FORMS BRANDING*" feature.

If you want their logo to be removed you will need to upgrade to a paid plan.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  

Just to elaborate, with the recent release of our referral program, we completely removed all branding everywhere for customers on our paid plans (forms, emails, etc.).  We include simple branding like "Powered by Cognito Forms" for customers on our free Individual plan, which double as referral links that can help these customers earn credits they can apply in the future to a paid account. However, for all forms existing prior to this release, we do not show branding, as we felt it was not appropriate to introduce this branding without warning or consent.

Comment: @JamieThomas Thank you for commenting. I was unaware of that. Would you like me to add it to the answer so as to make it more complete? Could you provide a link as well?

Comment: @marikamitos, no, your answer is complete from a forward-looking basis.  I was just clarifying what changed for existing customers.  Here is a link announcing our referral program: http://blog.cognitoforms.com/recommend-cognito-forms-and-receive-a-20-referral-bonus